# How to include pulseaudio core headers?

Tags: c, linux, yocto, pulseaudio

I am writing a program which should get sound from a pulseaudio source. I took `pacat.c` source file as an example.

Some of functions are declared in `/pulsecore/*.h`
I include them into my source code:

`#include <pulsecore/log.h>`

`#include <pulsecore/core-error.h>`

`#include <pulsecore/macro.h>`

`#include <pulsecore/g711.h>`

`#include <pulsecore/core-util.h>`

But compiler can't find them.
`fatal error: pulsecore/log.h: No such file or directory`

I build pulseaudio 9.0 with Yocto.

In /$BUILDSDIR/pulseaudio/9.0-r0/image there are no such headers. But they  exist in pulseaudio source code and also there
`/pulseaudio/9.0-r0/package/usr/src/debug/pulseaudio/9.0-r0/pulseaudio-9.0/src/pulsecore/`

Is there any special option for pulseaduio to configure to copy headers into image? Or I should update yocto recipe to copy desired files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the $WORKDIR of pulseaudio you will find the folder **packages-split** containing each package and its content.

I am not sure whether what you try is possible, but the files you are trying to use are provided in the package **pulseaudio-dbg**. Which you could try yo install either via image recipe or in your local.conf. (IMAGE_INSTALL or CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL variables respectively)

You can find the package itself in $WORKDIR/deploy-[rpm|ipk|deb]/